# React Material: progressBar with mouse listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I've faced with problem using React and React Material-UI components. What I need:

1) User clicks button in my component - I should add mousemove listener to the page and show ProgressBar.
2) User moves mouse - I count events, and update my ProgressBar.
3) When count of events is 50, I remove mousemove listener and hide ProgressBar.

I tried to do this with React useEffect, useState Hooks, but it does not remove listener. I don't understand, why.

Here is my code:

```
  const [completed, setCompleted] = React.useState(0);
  const [keyGenState, setKeyGenState] = React.useState(0);

  const updateMousePosition = ev => {
    console.log("UMP");
    setCompleted(old => old + 1);
    /*I tried to check completed value here, but it always is 0 - maybe, React re-renders component on setState..
    And I decided to take useEffect hook (see below)*/
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(completed); /*Just to understand, what happens) */
    if (completed === 49) {
        return () => {
            /*When completed value is 50, this log message appears, but mouse listener still works! */
            console.log("Finish!");
            document.removeEventListener("mousemove", updateMousePosition);
            setKeyGenState(2);
          }
    }
  }, [completed]); 

  function handleChange(e) {
    switch (e.currentTarget.id) {
        /*startKeyGen - it is ID of my Button. When user clicks it, I show ProgressBar and add mousemove listener*/
        case "startKeyGen" : {
            setKeyGenState(1);
            document.addEventListener("mousemove", updateMousePosition);
            break;}
    }
  }

/*Other logics. And finally, JSX code for my ProgressBar from Material-UI*/
<LinearProgress hidden={keyGenState !== 1 } variant="determinate" value={completed} style={{marginTop: 10}} />
```

It looks really strange: why React ignores removeEventListener.
Please, explain, where is my mistake.

**UPD:** Thanks a lot! I used useCallback hook, in this manner:

```
  const updateMousePosition = React.useCallback(
(ev) => {
      //console.log("Calback");
      console.log(ev.clientX);
      setCompleted(old => old + 1);
    },
  [],
);
useEffect(() => {
  //console.log(completed); /*Just to understand, what happens) */
  if (completed === 49) {
      return () => {
        /*When completed value is 50, this log message appears, but mouse listener still works! */
          console.log("Finish!");
          document.removeEventListener("mousemove", updateMousePosition);
          setKeyGenState(2);
        }
  }
});
```

But I still don't understand completely.. So, when I used useCallback with empty dependencies array, this function (updateMousePosition), will be unchanged during all "life" of my component?
 And in useEffect I remove mouseListener. It is magic for me: why does useEffect ignore removing without useCallback?

Comment: Provide an online demo may help others understanding the problem you are facing quickly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `React.useCallback` for `updateMousePosition`. Every change in your component creates new function (reference). So `React.useEffect` remove last `updateMousePosition` but doesn't remove added in `handleChange`.

Comment: How should I use it? I don't understand, when should callback execute

Comment: Please read about [React.useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)
`const updateMousePosition = React.useCallback(() => {
    setCompleted(old => old + 1);
  }, []);`

Comment: I forgot about useEffect dep. add `updateMousePosition` to dep array. `[completed, updateMousePosition]`

Comment: So, when we add dependencies into useEffect, it will call only when completed changes, and updateMousePosition changes? And updateMousePosition will not change (thanks useCallback), so useEffect will call only when completed changes?

Comment: Exactly. useEffect will call only in this case.